# Docker Desktop installation failed (windows 10)

Tags: docker

So I'm trying to install Docker Desktop 4.13.1 on Windows 10 but I get this error after a while,

```
**Installation Failed**
Component CommunityInstaller.AutoStartAction failed: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run' is denied.
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

I've tried disabling my antivirus software but that didn't help. I can't even find anything relating to this topic on the internet. I don't know how to provide the necessary permissions to Docker.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after a lot of headbanging, I finally found a fix. This may not work for you but it's worth trying.

First, open command prompt and run,

`wsl --status`

If you get something like "you have an update," you're at the right place. Then run,

`wsl --install -d ubuntu`

Let it finish and then run,

`wsl --update`

Then reboot your system and open the docker installer again. It should install fine now.